# Printed Pdf show no content of filled AcroForms

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, acrofields

I am using itextSharp 4.1.6 to add AcroFields to an existing PDF and in a second step, fill these fields with content.
When I open these documents in Adobe Reader, I can see the content. When I try to print the document, all filled fields are empty.

This happens with both, editable and flattened PDFs. 
'GenerateAppearances' is set to True.
Due to the current licence concept I cannot upgrade to another version.
My code:

```
var dlg = new OpenFileDialog
{
    FileName = "",
    Filter = @"pdf|*.pdf"
};
if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

// first step: create field
var outputpath1 = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), string.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")));
var pdfReader1 = new PdfReader(dlg.FileName);
var output1 = new FileStream(outputpath1, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
var stamper1 = new PdfStamper(pdfReader1, output1);
InsertTextfield(stamper1, 1, 20, 500, 150, 100, "test");
stamper1.Close();
pdfReader1.Close();

// second step: insert some text
var outputpath2 = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), string.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")));
var pdfReader2 = new PdfReader(outputpath1);
var output2 = new FileStream(outputpath2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
var stamper2 = new PdfStamper(pdfReader2, output2);
stamper2.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;
var formData = stamper2.AcroFields;
formData.SetField("test", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ");
stamper2.Close();
pdfReader2.Close();

Process.Start(outputpath2);
```

And the `InsertTextField`:

```
private static void InsertTextfield(PdfStamper stamper, int page, float x, float y, float width, float height, string fieldname)
{
    var field = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(stamper.Writer, true, false, 500);
    field.SetWidget(new Rectangle(x, y, x + width, y + height), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
    field.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
    field.FieldName = fieldname;
    stamper.AddAnnotation(field, page);
}
```

For the document, just create a new word document, add some text and save as PDF. Choose this document to start with.

So, how can I get my filed contents to show up in prints?

**EDIT:** Added code

Comment: 1. Share your code 2. Share your documents 3. Try to reproduce the issue in the most recent release, 5.5.9.

Comment: *This happens with both, editable and flattened PDFs* - if that also happens with flattened documents, something is very fishy, unless you use optional content groups which are switched off while printing.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. Now, try again with iTextSharp `5.5.9`.

Comment: @ Amedee Van Gasse: Same result when using 5.5.9

Answer (score 0):

You should create your TextField via the TextField constructor.
Works for me in iTextSharp 4.1.6

```
private static void InsertTextfield(PdfStamper stamper, int page, float x, float y, float width, float height, string fieldname)
{
    var field = new TextField(stamper.Writer, new Rectangle(x, y, x + width, y + height), fieldname);
    field.Options = TextField.MULTILINE;
    stamper.AddAnnotation(field.GetTextField(), page);
}
```